# How to find the closest object to the camera?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am working on an algorithm which can find the point where the object is closest to the camera. I have found some help online by using meanshift. I have pasted the code to do that. How the code works is : it uses a track_window to track the closest object. But the problem is I don't know how to find the location of the closest object.
What I have tried:
I can make the track_window go through the full image and thus narrow down the area of interest but its too long and I still won't know the exact location.
Could someone help me find the closes object to the camera?
Here is my code:

```
    /*
 * back_project.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Mar 8, 2015
 *      Author: sushrut
 */

#include "backProject.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

/// Global Variables
Mat src; Mat hsv; Mat hue;
int bins = 25;
Rect track_window = cv::Rect(250, 250, 50, 50);
int x=1, y=1, wr=1, hr=1;

/// Function Headers
void Hist_and_Backproj(int, void* );

/** @function main */
int back_proj_main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);

    if(!cap.isOpened())
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the first web cam" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    while(true)
    {
        Mat src;
        bool bSuccess = cap.read(src);
        if(!bSuccess)
        {
            cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream 1" << endl;
            break;
        }

        /// Transform it to HSV
        cvtColor( src, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV );

        /// Use only the Hue value
        hue.create( hsv.size(), hsv.depth() );
        int ch[] = { 0, 0 };
        mixChannels( &hsv, 1, &hue, 1, ch, 1 );

        /// Create Trackbar to enter the number of bins
        char* window_image = "Source image";
        namedWindow( window_image, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
        createTrackbar("* Hue  bins: ", window_image, &bins, 180, Hist_and_Backproj );
        Hist_and_Backproj(0, 0);

        // create a rectangle on the image
        rectangle(src, Point(x,y), Point(x+wr, y+hr), Scalar(0, 250, 0));
        /// Show the image
        imshow( window_image, src );

        if (waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
        {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    // TODO release the capture
    return 0;
}


/**
 * @function Hist_and_Backproj
 * @brief Callback to Trackbar
 */
void Hist_and_Backproj(int, void* )
{
    MatND hist;
    int histSize = MAX( bins, 2 );
    float hue_range[] = { 0, 180 };
    const float* ranges = { hue_range };

    /// Get the Histogram and normalize it
    calcHist( &hue, 1, 0, Mat(), hist, 1, &histSize, &ranges, true, false );
    normalize( hist, hist, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

    /// Get Backprojection
    MatND backproj;
    calcBackProject( &hue, 1, 0, hist, backproj, &ranges, 1, true );

    /// Draw the backproj
    imshow( "BackProj", backproj );

    // code to create a meanshift
    meanShift(backproj,track_window, TermCriteria(TermCriteria::COUNT|TermCriteria::EPS, 10, 1));

    // update the value of recctange
    x = track_window.x;
    y = track_window.y;
    wr = track_window.width;
    hr = track_window.height;
    cout << "values: " << x << ", " << y << ", " << wr << ", " << hr << endl;

    /// Draw the histogram
    int w = 400; int h = 400;
    int bin_w = cvRound( (double) w / histSize );
    Mat histImg = Mat::zeros( w, h, CV_8UC3 );

    for( int i = 0; i < bins; i ++ )
    { rectangle( histImg, Point( i*bin_w, h ), Point( (i+1)*bin_w, h - cvRound( hist.at<float>(i)*h/255.0 ) ), Scalar( 0, 0, 255 ), -1 ); }

    imshow( "Histogram", histImg );
}
```

Refrences:
http://www.opencv.org.cn/opencvdoc/2.3.1/html/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/back_projection/back_projection.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, it is impossible to detect which object is closest to the camera if you have only one frame and one camera - object relative position.
You should process video sequence and track feature points to determine positions of objects in the coordinate frame of the camera.

You should study some materials on multiple view geometry. For example, lectures of professor Daniel Cremers on YouTube. A book by Hartley and Zisserman is also very good.

**Update after reading the comment**

It is unclear what points you mean. Are they pixel coordinates of the object in the image or points in 3D Euclidean space?

If first, then you can proceed in the following. Backproject returns you an image, where each pixel contains a probability of belonging to the object. You could threshold this image to throw out very low probabilities, filter the result from noise, refine with morphological operators (erosion, closing) thus getting a blob of pixels, most probably belonging to you object. Then you can find its bounding rectangle. If you do not want to use backproject, because it doesn't always find the object, then you can use [2D feature detectors and matchers](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/features2d.html) from OpenCV. They can estimate locations of some "extreme" points, belonging to the object.

In the second case the task looks like a task of SLAM (Simultaneous Localization and Mapping). It is more complex subject. I again reference you to multiview geometry and SLAM courses. This task also heavily uses 2D feature points.

Comment: Hi wl2776, thanks for the reply but i am currently tracking the closest object to the camera, but it is only in the track_window specified in the start of the program. I want to do it over the whole image and also find the location of the closest object.

Comment: Hi wl2776, thanks again for your help. I just read your answer. I will re-search more into the areas you have pointed to and learn about them. My questions haven't been clear, let me clear it up. I am trying to create a self-navigating robot using camera as the eyes for the robot and opencv as the brain of the robot. So I used meanShift algorithm as it helps in finding objects with high intensity and just move away from them. You seem quite clear on this stuff, would it be possible to chat with you for 10 minutes? It would help me a lot in understanding the subject.

Comment: Hi! I'm not so good in robotics. Just touched this subject a bit. Anyway, googling for SLAM and "Robot mapping" will give you a lot of useful information. I also recommend several online courses: "Programming a Robotic car" by Sebastian Thrun, "Introduction to Robot Mapping" and other courses by Cyrill Stachniss, and "Mobile Navigation for flying robots" by Jurgen Sturm. S. Thrun also has written a very good textbook on robotics.